# A statement about modulo property from The Art of Computer Programming

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In the book The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 3, section 6.4 Hashing, there is a statement paraphrased here as the following:

If `A` is relatively prime to `w`, we can find a constant `A'` with `AA' mod w = 1`; this implies that `K = (A'(AK mod w)) mod w`.

I understand the first part, which is modular inverse. But I'm struggling to prove the second part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working in the ring of integers modulo $w$ 
we thus have that $K = 1\cdot K = (A' \cdot A) \cdot K = A' \cdot (A \cdot K)$.

This is what this statement is saying.

Comment: I understand $ K \equiv A'(AK) \;(mod\;w) $. But how do you go from there to $ K = (A'(AK\;mod\;w))\;mod\;w $?

Comment: @Nowibananatzki because every $\cdot$ above is multiplication modulo $w$.

Comment: @Nowibananatzki As $A (A' K \pmod w) \pmod w = AA'K \pmod w$. It doesn't matter if you do reductions inbetween multiplications if you do more than one. The result is the same as if you had done one ordinary multiplication and then reduced.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you know what this property is called? So I can search it online.

Comment: @Nowibananatzki it’s part of the proof that integers modulo $w$ form a ring. Which is just general algebra (dividing out modulo an ideal).